# Connect all radio buttons with bold line css

Tags: html, css

I ran into a design problem where i needed to connect all radio buttons with green line.
Below screen shows the current vs desired version
I needed help to draw lones across all radio buttons and fill the area with another color.
Current css+html is attached
If anyone can help, please do help.Thanks for your time.

```css
.radio-grid-ctrl {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.radio-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.radio-grid input[type="radio"] {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.labelTheme {
  color: #59ce59;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-grid input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #ed1c24 !important;
  accent-color: #ed1c24 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-grid">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio1" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio2" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio3" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio4" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio5" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio6" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio7" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio8" value="">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-grid-ctrl" name="radio-group" id="radio9" value="">
</div>
```

Its a custom css, i have tried to use grid-template css but failed absolutely with everything falling apart.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "connect all radio buttons with green line"? / Share what you want the result to be?

Comment: What have you tried? I see no code that would attempt to do that. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please also check that you have shown us an image - I can't see one.